# Cut/mask multiple planes along a circle at once

Tags: mesh, masking, knife-tool

My challenge is to create some type of a radial chart so I created planes with an array. I scaled the planes randomly to generate "fake data". Now I want to cut all the bars (planes) along a circle which represents "0".

It is possible to do with the knife project, but this means I would have to do this for every bar?
I would prefer a mask which would automatically hide everything below the inner circle, but I was not able to manage this with the vertex groups.

Any ideas please on how I can make this in a more performant way? I'm using 2.8

[image]

[image]

Comment: first join all your shapes into one object, then cut off with boolean or knife project, then if necessary separate by loose parts?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all your objects's origins are in the center of the world. Go into Object mode, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to center the 3D cursor, then <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, Right Click > Set Origin > To 3D cursor.

Also, apply the scale transform with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Scale or go to Object > Apply > Scale

Give this material to all your objects (only the alpha part is important):

[image]

The "Length" node is obtained by using a "Vector Math" node and set the operation accordingly. Similarly for the "Greater than" node, you must first add a "Math" node and change the operation.

To give this material to all your objects, give it to one of them, then select them all with <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> click on the object with the material. Then go to Object > Make Links > Materials or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > Materials

If you use Eevee, make sure to set the alpha blend mode to clip :

[image]

Tweak the Math node threshold :

[image]

You can then add a driver to use your bezier circle as a visual guide, and mask the bars under it when you scale it :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: EDIT: this works when all lines are aligned to each other but not when they are starting from different positions from the center as in my example.

Comment: Maybe try my method (join all the objects together and apply a boolean), or share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  by the way, how did you make the original shape?

Comment: If their origin is in the world center and you have applied the scale with CTRL A, the shader should work. Could you share your file with the link @moonboots provided ?

Comment: @moonboots and Gorgious : I added the file to the question. Thx for your time.

Comment: so it looks like you've already cut off a circle, no?

Comment: @moonboots ah sorry my bad, this was already the workaround, I'll re-upload the inital piece

Comment: I don't see any link

Comment: @moonboots just added now. thx

Comment: so what about joining all your beams into one object, then use a boolean to hide the center and make a perfect circular hole?

Comment: @StefanWasserbauer You need to apply uniform scale to all your objects. Select them and press CTRL + A > Scale or go to Object > Apply > Scale

Comment: @StefanWasserbauer Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

We lack a bit of informations about what you want to do but let say you just want to dig a hole circle on your shape:

- Select all your beams, join them with <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

- Create a cylinder, make it invisible in Viewport Display and in Visibility.

[image]

- Give your beams object a *Boolean* modifier with the cylinder as *Object* and *Operation* > *Difference*.

[image]

- You can change the cylinder radius, you can use shapekeys if you want to animate. You can also apply the *Boolean*. If you want to separate the beams again, press <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts*.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution by now and the most straight forward. As I like the solution of @Gorgious too it's quite hard which one to mark as the final solution,... Thank you guys for your effort!